# Passing values from select tag to views.py

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, django-views, django-templates, html-select

I want to know how passing option's value to a function in views.py works in Django.

Here is a simple html code contains select tag with some options in it.

Thanks in advance.

```
<select>
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you need to pass it using a form. If this is how your form looks, give your select field a name so you can retrieve it in your view.

```
<form action="{% url 'url_name_of_view' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %} #include this if you are sending a post request
<select name='name_of_select'>
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<Button type='submit' />
</form>
```

now, in your views,

```
select_value = request.POST.get('name_of_select') # this variable now contains the selected value.
```

Answer (score -1):

there
if you do have models.py which you should, create a model first and add a choicefield to it and use a tuple of tuples to pass in the value you want.
Then through a form you will be able to reference it in your views.py and know what value is selected by the user.

Comment: Thanks, Papis for your reply but I don't work with models because I use Realtime Database by Firebase, so I work with views only. Is there any way to pass the values without using models that works with sql ?

Comment: Can you just walk me through the organization of you database. By that I mean at least you have to link in one way or another the views and the database since they need to communicate.  Sorry for this question because I am really used to firebase.

Comment: Sorry, Papis. I tried another solution and it works. Thanks for your effort.