# Send JavaScript value to method on views.py (Django)

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I'm using django (4.0.4) to develop a 'simple' interface with three dropdown list with the data of the last two depends of the value selected of the first.

This is the front:

[image]

This is the project structure dir:

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── example_web
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── web
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── style.css
    │   └── js
    │       └── app.js
    ├── templates
    │   ├── index.html
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

This is urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from web.views import homePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', homePageView),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from jf.clients import RPClient




def homePageView(request):

    a = _get_coaches()
    b = _get_devices()
 
    value_js = request.GET.get('id')
    print(value_js)

    context = {
        'coaches': a,
        'devices': b,

    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
 

def _get_coaches():
    client = RPClient('dev', proxy_ip='10.10.1.15')
    a = client.get_current_value('status/coach')

    return [i['id'] for i in a['items']]


def _get_devices(request):
    client = RPClient('dev', proxy_ip='10.10.1.15')
    a = client.get_current_value('status/cable/X')
    
    # !!!!!!!!!!

    # HERE is where in the X place I want to store the value_js variable 

    return [i['id'] for i in a['items']]
```

This is the js, css and html

```js
function value_id() {
  coach_id = document.getElementById("coaches").value;
  window.alert('ID Selected: ' + coach_id);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '',
    data: {
      'id': coach_id
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-top: 50;
  margin-bottom: 50;

}

section {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display:inline-block;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding-left: 180;
  margin-top: 250;
  width: 225px;

}

div {
  position: fixed;
}

select option:hover {
    margin: 40px;
    background: #4780D5;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.selectColor {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fafafa;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4780D5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:#fafafa;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
    {% load static %}
    
    <title>Website</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
    
    <html>   
        <body>
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Example</h1>
            </div>
            
            <div>
            <section>
              <select id='coaches' class="selectColor" onchange="value_id()">
                <option  value="">Select Coach</option>
                {% for coach in coaches%}
                <option id='test' value="{{ coach }}">Coach {{coach }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>            
            </section>
    
            <section>
              <select id='devices'  class="selectColor" onchange="value_device()">
                <option value="">Select Device</option>
                {% for device in devices%}
                <option style="text-transform:uppercase;" value="{{ device }}">{{ device }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </section>
    
    
          </div>
          </body>
    </html>
    
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
```

The first dropdown is autocompleted by making a get request to an endpoint like **/status/coach**  and I get the ID.

So the first dropdown list would look something like this:

- Coach 1
- Coach 2
- Coach 3

I need the second dropdown to also make a get request to the same endpoint adding the id it picks up after at the end, i.e if I select on the dropdown elements 'Coach 2' the enpoint will be **/status/coach/2**

But I don't know how to send the value of the id that I store in coach_id on js file and to a method in the views file.

According to examples that I have read here they proposed two things: send this variable with ajax (I've never been using js until this moment so there are probably things that are wrong) but when I try this I always get None as a value of the 'coach_id' variable and only appears when I reload the page on the django debug, not appears when I select an item from the list, only the *window.alert* is working...what I am doing wrong?

Another alternative I have seen is to put the section and select tag sctructure inside a form , like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67971511), but I don't want a post button with a form

So...how can I send the ID value of the selected car to the views file on *get_devices()* method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` as the argument to the `onchange` call and in javascript you can get this as element.

```
<select id='coaches' class="selectColor" onchange="value_id()">
```

In javascript

```
function value_id(thisValueElement) {
 const value = thisValueElement.value
 
 const endpoint = "{% url 'your_homepage_view_url' %}
 fetch(endpoint + "?coach_id=" + value)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => { 
    // Return JsonResponse from server and get the value here.
  })
}
```

And then in your view you get that from the GET request.

```
def homePageView(request):
    coach_id = request.GET.get("coach_id", default_id_here_if_not_omit_this)
    a = _get_coaches()
    b = _get_devices()
 
    value_js = request.GET.get('id')
    print(value_js)

    context = {
        'coaches': a,
        'devices': b,

    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: thanks :) but how can I send this to the method on views.py file?

Comment: See my updated answer